# Probabilistic upper bounds on importance sampling error

Tags: references, error, mse, importance-sampling

Consider the importance sampling estimation error
$$
e_n(f) = \int f d\mu - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \rho(x_i), \qquad x_i \sim \lambda,\, \rho = \tfrac{d\mu}{d\lambda},
$$
where $\mu$ and $\lambda$ the target and proposal distributions, respectively. I know a few probabilistic upper bounds on $|e_n(f)|$, from
$$
\text{Var}(e_n(f)) \le \frac{\|\rho\|_\infty \|f\|_{L^2(\mu)}^2 }{n},
$$
which can be refined to
$$
\mathbb{E}|e_n(f)| \le \|f\|_{L^2(\mu)}\left( \sqrt{a}/\sqrt{n} +2 \sqrt{\mathbb{P}(\rho(X) > a)} \right), \quad \forall a > 0,\, X \sim \mu. 
$$
Similarily to the first inequality, we have
$$
\text{Var}(e_n(f)) \le \frac{\|f\|_\infty^2 D_{\chi^2}(\mu, \lambda) }{n}.
$$
The first and the third inequalities are immediate; the second inequality is [from Chatterjee and Diaconis (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.01437)). Here $d_{\chi^2}(\mu, \lambda) = \int \rho d\mu - 1$.

**Question.** What are other known (and interesting) approaches to bounding $e_n$ in probability?

I did some research, but couldn't find anything more. (I could be using the wrong keywords; the references I found were very applied.)

**Note.** I'm not interested in asymptotic results, unless they come with an explicit convergence rate. The error should be quantified when approximations are used.

---

**Background on importance sampling.**

Let $\mathbb{M}$ be a measurable space, let $\mu$ and $\lambda$ be two probability measures on $\mathbb{M}$, with $\mu$ absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$, and let $f : \mathbb{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable. The problem is to estimate 
$$
 I = \int f d\mu
$$
given a random sample $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ from $\lambda$. The (un-normalized) importance sampling estimate of $I $ is
$$
 I_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)\tfrac{d\mu}{d\lambda}(x_i).
$$